# How to fix these minor error related to Jar files and lib of jsf and spring in Myeclipse IDE

Tags: spring, icefaces, myeclipse

### **here the log file I am unable to fix the problems.**

I have restarted the webserver,

cleaned the project and tried rebuilding but still no luck to understand what exactly is wrong.

I tried searching on SOF to fix the problem by removing the conflicting jar files but still no success.

Anyone out there to understand the log file which is below.

```html
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\MyEclipse9\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.6.0.013\bin;C:\MyEclipse9\Common\plugins\com.genuitec.eclipse.easie.tomcat.myeclipse_9.0.0.me201105051700\tomcat\bin
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:05 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 313 ms
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\i\Desktop\Workspaces\MyEclipse 9\.metadata\.me_tcat\webapps\na20\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-3.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\i\Desktop\Workspaces\MyEclipse 9\.metadata\.me_tcat\webapps\na20\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\i\Desktop\Workspaces\MyEclipse 9\.metadata\.me_tcat\webapps\na20\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\i\Desktop\Workspaces\MyEclipse 9\.metadata\.me_tcat\webapps\na20\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\i\Desktop\Workspaces\MyEclipse 9\.metadata\.me_tcat\webapps\na20\WEB-INF\lib\servletapi-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:11 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/na20'
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:22 PM org.icefaces.impl.push.servlet.ICEpushResourceHandler <init>
INFO: Ajax Push Resource Handling not available: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/icepush/servlet/MainServlet
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:22 PM org.icefaces.util.EnvConfig init
INFO: ICEfaces Configuration: 
org.icefaces.render.auto: true [default]
org.icefaces.autoid: true [default]
org.icefaces.aria.enabled: true [default]
org.icefaces.blockUIOnSubmit: false [default]
org.icefaces.compressDOM: false [default]
org.icefaces.compressResources: true [default]
org.icefaces.connectionLostRedirectURI: null [default]
org.icefaces.deltaSubmit: false [default]
org.icefaces.lazyPush: true [default]
org.icefaces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI: null [default]
org.icefaces.standardFormSerialization: false [default]
org.icefaces.strictSessionTimeout: false [default]
org.icefaces.windowScopeExpiration = 1000 [default]
org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration: null [default]
org.icefaces.uniqueResourceURLs: true [default]
org.icefaces.lazyWindowScope: true [default]
org.icefaces.disableDefaultErrorPopups: false [default]

Dec 9, 2016 12:16:22 PM org.icefaces.impl.push.servlet.ICEpushResourceHandler <init>
INFO: Ajax Push Resource Handling not available: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/icepush/servlet/MainServlet
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:22 PM org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.DOMRenderKit <clinit>
INFO: 
ICEsoft Technologies Inc.
ICEfaces 2.0.2
Build number: 8
Revision: 24561

Dec 9, 2016 12:16:23 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.4
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:23 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isCoallesceResources(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)Z
 at org.icefaces.impl.application.CoalescingResourceHandler$RegisterListener.processEvent(CoalescingResourceHandler.java:195)
 at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2144)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:302)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:600)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:369)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4334)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isCoallesceResources(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)Z
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4334)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isCoallesceResources(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)Z
 at org.icefaces.impl.application.CoalescingResourceHandler$RegisterListener.processEvent(CoalescingResourceHandler.java:195)
 at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2168)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2144)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:302)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:600)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:369)
 at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
 ... 24 more
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/na20] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:24 PM org.icefaces.impl.push.servlet.ICEpushResourceHandler notifyContextShutdown
INFO: MainServlet not found in application scope: java.lang.NullPointerException
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:24 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:25 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:25 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:25 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/20  config=null
Dec 9, 2016 12:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 19743 ms
```

Comment: icefaces jar is missing in your runtime, how are you running the application ?

Comment: icefaces-2.0.2.jar is added now 

I am using Server tab to stop webserver and deploy the project , then trying to access using http://localhost:8080/na20/


But 404 error displays saying resource not found.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /na20/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /na20/

description The requested resource (/na20/) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.13

Comment: @kuhajeyan even after adding icefaces jar added, the log has same errors. [link]http://pastebin.com/RbrAQs1j

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a class loading issue. Is the icefaces jar included at multiple levels in the Tomcat class loading hierarchy? Looking at the stack trace, the processEvent method in the org.icefaces.impl.application.CoalescingResourceHandler.RegisterListener class is calling method isCoallesceResources in the org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils class. Now, those two classes should be in the same icefaces jar file, and so should be at compatible versions. However, the called method is not in the Envutils class that is currently loaded (note that the method was added in icefaces 3.3, but also the CoelescingResourceHandler class was added then). So it would seem that the EventUtils class was loaded from an icefaces jar file earlier than version 3.3, whilst the CoalescingResourceHandler class was loaded from an icefaces jar file of version 3.3 or above.

Ensure that all icefaces.jar files in the [Tomcat class loading hierarchy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) are of the same version or, better still, ensure that the jar file doesn't appear in more than one level of the hierarchy.